# Asymptotic bound of a function depends on that function

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I have a function $s(x,y)$ where $x,y,s$ are positive integers. $s$ is a bit strange, in that its growth depends on itself, namely $s=O(x^2\log(y+s))$. I would like to find an asymptotic upper bound for $s$ that does not depend on itself but I am unsure of how to do this. More generally, I am also curious if there is a general way to solve other "self referential" bound problems. All Google searches assumed that I wanted to bound functions satisfying recurrence relations.

I know that there exists an $M$ and a $C>0$ such that, when $\max(s(x,y),x,y) > M$,
$$s(x,y) < Cx^2log(y+s(x,y)),$$
however I can't figure out how to isolate $s$. I am okay with a weaker upper bound, but I don't know if or how, using the information that I have, I can prove any upper bound not dependent on $s$. Also, I have some control over the definition of $s$, so if it would be easier to bound, $s$ can be monotonically increasing in both variables.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2797143/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92359/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  See my comments on CS.SE for requests to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing naively.

$s
\lt c x^2\log(y+s))
$.

Suppose
$s \approx x^ay^b$.
Then
$x^ay^b
\lt c x^2\log(y+x^ay^b))
$
or
$x^{a-2}y^b
\lt c \log(y+x^ay^b))
$.

If $a > 2$ or $y > 0$
the left side will be too large,
so
$a=2$ and $y=0$.

This gives
$s = \Theta(x^2)$
which does work.